# what should i do my group memeber are not doing any work in fyp

Tags: projects

I am doing my final year project and my group members are not doing there work and also they have no interest in it .. after many presentation i ask our professor about this situation and he said u made your own group so i can do nothing about this.. so far i am doing project work and i didn't mind it but problem is that in my final presentation they might fail us or because of there laziness teacher might give me poor grades because other member don't know how project is worked (making website in fyp) and they are not interested also... so i am very tensed what should i do...

Comment: Sometimes, the point is to demonstrate what you did/contributed to make the project & the group work. There's not much more you can do. If the prof really punishes you for being in the wrong group - yes, it's unfair, choose your next group carefully, and early.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you have to focus on the project and not to be discouraged by your colleagues. You have made the right decision by informing your professor. Try to let your colleagues realize how important this is to you and your future. The silver lining in this is that you're getting more experience than anyone of them. Don't throw in the towel yet.

Comment: as a last option i email them and i point the problem to both of them in peaceful manner  and one of them show some interest . so may b thing will b better in fews days thanks for u advice.

Comment: Omer, you are welcome. Thank God that things are now getting better. Do enjoy your project.